# Zapier: How to skip a step in multi-step zaps

Tags: zapier

I'm looking for a way to skip steps (but not abort the Zap altogether) in a multi-stage Zap.  For example, if one of the trigger event's values are a certain value, it doesn't need to run Step 2 (which might have been a creation or deletion step), but should continue on to Step 3.

I believe I can do this by using the `Code by Zapier` service to call a separate `Webhook by Zapier` Zap and optionally calling (before that one) another such webhook if it meets a criteria.  But that's incredibly hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zapier now supports branch logic, called Paths.  This is currently the best non-code method.  It doesn't loop back into a common endpoint, but one could work around that by having them all end with a Webhook POST to a common Webhook receiver that ties up the end portion of the Zap.

Answer (score 1):

Zapier does also support code steps. Obviously, this kind of defeats the purpose of using zapier to avoid coding, but if the step was simple (or maintaining two zaps was hard), you could write out the request and surround it in an if block

```
if (doThisStep) {
  const payload = { name: 'Bob' };
  fetch('http://some.example/', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(payload) })
    .then((res) => callback(null, res.json())
    .catch(callback);
} else {
  // Don't forget the callback if you skip the step!
  callback(null, { skipped: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zapier now has support for Custom Filters (https://zapier.com/learn/how-to-use-zapier/custom-filters/).

You can setup a filter based on the previous steps that essentially says - "Only proceed to the next step of this Zap if xxx conditions are met".

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't skip steps, it only ends processing through the Zap altogether, unless I've missed something of course.  What I'm needing is a way to do a `GOTO`, not a `RETURN`/`EXIT`.

Comment: Aha - Sorry, misread the question. The only way around as of now would be to setup two different zaps :) One with the first set of steps and the other with the second.